# Paypal In-Context guest checkout

Tags: express, paypal, checkout

Is it possible to use paypal in-context checkout with guest checkout?
So the problem is that i don't see a button in popup dialog "debit or credit card checkout" currently i am testing this in sandbox. The option allow checkout as guest is enabled in the sandbox merchant account.

Answer (score 1):

I have a working copy of "In Context" Express Checkout and guest checkout functions as intended in the sandbox environment. Be sure you are passing "SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole" in your SetExpressCheckout API call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but i am using the PHP SDK http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/ there is no such option. It seems it is not available in REST API. Is there a solution or a workaround for this?

Comment: We've tested this in our own test environment and were able to successfully use Guest Checkout. Are you in the US? I ask because offerings are sometimes different depending on the country you are in.

Comment: No i use the de_DE locale

Comment: Does your Express Checkout Implementation offer guest checkout without the "In-Context" script?